# Displaying table columns vertically with divider android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am new to android 
and I want to create a simple table with 2 columns in it. so i looked for some example and found nice one and created table like this:

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Open..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-O"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Save..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-S"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

Now i get table with two rows and each row has two columns without any separator. I want to have a divider in two columns like any normal table. Can anyone please help me with it.
Tnx in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution as suggested in the android.com tutorials: Simply add an empty view with a background as divider:

```
<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Answer (score 1):

one thing you could do is create a png of a vertical divider and place it between your tablerows.

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Save..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
<ImageView android:layout_width="3dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-S"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

and set the source of the of the image view to your image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i try to do as u said i get some exception :(

Comment: did you create a resource for the image source?  What is the exception